# Custom shortcuts for missing keys on Acer Aspire

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I bought an Acer Aspire that lacks Home, End, PgUp, and PgDn keys.  How do I make custom shortcuts for these using Ubuntu 18's built-in feature?

Comment: Does ALT+ up or down ARROW KEY work for PgUp and PgDn?

Comment: For Home and End, you can usually use CTRL+ALT+UP-ARROW or CTRL+ALT+DOWN-ARROW.

Comment: No, those aren't working for me.